# Getting birth certificate of German born in Romania in 1895

Tags: birth-records, 1890s, romania

My grandfather was a German born in Romania in 1895. I need to get a copy of his birth certificate to prove he was German, as I need to prove he was German to apply for a German passport for my elderly mom.

How do I go about getting it or proof of his German heritage?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE. Was your grandfather born in what was Romania in 1895, or is the place now in Romania? Some Transylvanian and Banat records are available online or have been indexed, but you need to know the place (also true of the answer in the question linked above).

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  If you (or anyone else) use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with additional explanation about why the duplicate might not apply then it can be reviewed for quick re-opening.